# Invoking a Function by String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, function

After reading many times this question and its accepted answer [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

I tried to do it on my own. but I think its my unlucky day today that what I had tried was not working. I created already a fiddle for my testing

```
//the function I want to invoke by String
function CheckMe() {
    return "haha";
}

//the function that will search for the function and invoke it
function InvokeChecking(func2check) {
    var fn = func2check;
    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
        return = fn(); //invoke the function
    }
}

//the event listener  ( ´ ▽ ` )ﾉ
$("#checker").click(function () {
    alert("event is working");
    alert(InvokeChecking("CheckMe"));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/qKHpu/2/

the thing I want to do is to invoke the function I declared by using string and get its return value. So I followed what I saw here in SO using the `(fn==='function')` argument. but it seems not working for me.

where I went wrong?

**NOTE**: I already check it in firebug and my function exist... Did I fall in a scoping problem? or something?

Comment: please include all relevant parts of your question **in** your question.

Comment: I think I already put the needed parts to understand my question... and there is a fiddle already...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qKHpu/7/ typeof fn is actually `string`, not `function`

Comment: @Mahan A link to an external resource does not count as "including".

Comment: @Mahan added my answer below :)

Comment: typo: return = fn(); //invoke the function - remove the = sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qKHpu/8/

You need to pass in the literal name of the function, without quotes (`"`), otherwise it'll be treated as a literal string, which is meaningless

```
alert(InvokeChecking(CheckMe)); // instead of alert(InvokeChecking("CheckMe"));
```

Comment: sorry... SO is blocking the potato... I won't forget to accept this after 7 mins

Comment: Strange, not sure who downvoted this answer ... it's also correct =/

Comment: someone downvote-stalked me :S, 16 seconds after, I got another downvote :(, o well :(

Answer (score 3):

A function by name, as the related answer you mentioned says, is invoked by:

```
var function_name = 'alert';
window[function_name]('hello world');
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/qKHpu/4/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qKHpu/27/

check it work some ..